# parsing json arrays in IOS

Tags: ios, json

I found this part of code in a tutorial for parsing json objects:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSLog(@"connectionDidFinishLoading");
    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[self.responseData length]);

    // convert to JSON
    NSError *myError = nil;
    NSDictionary *res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&myError];

    // show all values
    for(id key in res) {

        id value = [res objectForKey:key];

        NSString *keyAsString = (NSString *)key;
        NSString *valueAsString = (NSString *)value;

        NSLog(@"key: %@", keyAsString);
        NSLog(@"value: %@", valueAsString);
    }

    // extract specific value...
    NSArray *results = [res objectForKey:@"results"];

    for (NSDictionary *result in results) {
        NSString *icon = [result objectForKey:@"icon"];
        NSLog(@"icon: %@", icon);
    }

}
```

I was able to use that code and parse data when my JSON object was of that form:

`{"data_1":0,"data_2":0,"Plato 1":0,"data_3":0....}` and I was just searching for specific keys, named data_1 and so on.

Now I am fetching data over DB so my JSON object is an array.

JSON object is of that form:

```
[{"0":"1","id":"1","1":"text1","image":"text2","2":"0"}]
```

What changes do I have to make?

Comment: I think you only have to change `NSDictionary *res` to `NSArray *res`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is simply wrong.  For the general case you should receive the parse result into an NSObject pointer, then test its type with `isKindOfClass`.  What you're getting back is not an NSDictionary but rather an NSArray containing one entry that is an NSDictionary.

Comment: can you provide sample code or any link for that? I want each object to be my single row of my DB.

Comment: @ghostrider - I could.  Or you could read the spec for isKindOfClass and figure it out.

Answer (score -1):

```
NSArray *calArray=[//---get columns from DB----//];
if (calArray) 
{
    for (int j=0; j<[calArray count]; j++) 
    {
        NSDictionary *dct=(NSDictionary *)[calArray objectAtIndex:j];
        NSString *string=(NSString *)[dct objectForKey:@"your_key"];
        [your_array addObject:string];

       // repeat the above code for more keys.
    }
}
```

Comment: I want it to give me all rows, not only one.